# How are header files organized in linux

Tags: c, linux

On linux, there is socket.h under many folders as shown below.

1. How is it decided as to what is stored under asm folder vs linux vs bits. I am assuming everything under sys is simply libc
2. In what order do the header files get resolved by gcc. Does it for example pick socket.h from sys, then linux, then sys, then bits so on?

/usr/include/sys/socket.h, (used by libc)

/usr/include/linux/socket.h

/usr/include/asm/socket.h

/usr/include/asm-generic/socket.h

/usr/include/bits/socket.h (included by libc)

Comment: Are you talking of application-level programming (apparently yes), or about kernel programming?? And why do you ask?? What matters is the "toplevel" header you should include, and that is documented.

Answer (score 4):

1) A bare `#include <socket.h>` won't work in default linux configurations:

```
fatal error: socket.h: No such file or directory
```

This means that you have to specify the subdirectory of a directory in the gcc search path also: `#include <sys/socket.h>` (relative to `/usr/include`, so the absolute path is `/usr/include/sys/socket.h`). To determine what header file to use, look at `man socket`.

In general `/usr/include/sys` contains end-user headers, whereas `bits`/`asm` contain intermediate headers, used by gcc and other headers. `/usr/include/linux` contains Linux-specific headers (often shared with the kernel, so it's description of kernel structures that may be useful for userspace programming).

Libc headers are generally scattered throughout the whole /usr/include. Gcc-specific headers are often in places like `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu` and such.

2) 
Here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html you can find more information about the GCC search paths. None of the guessed directories are searched, just `/usr/include` and others on the list in the link.

Answer (score 1):

## For General Files

This is very easy to do if you are using a gcc compiler

```
gcc -M filename.c
```

This should show you the complete list of dependencies for the compiled file. It will include the full path of all header files included in the compilation.

## For System Files

On a different note, if you are looking for system header files, like `socket.h` for example, you should have a look at the man page of socket

```
man socket
```

This should show you something like [this](http://linux.die.net/man/7/socket), which makes it pretty clear that the file you are looking for is `/usr/include/sys/socket.h`